# 360 degree Raycaster return closest intersect to set as focused target

Tags: three.js, collision

I would like to feed my move towards function a target.

To get that target I would like to raycast in a 360 degree bubble from 0 to 3 units all around my character.  Then I would like to have it return the closest  intersect so i may set it as the focus.

How can i get the raycaster to do this. From what I am reading, it only takes a linear line / direction as an argument.

Comment: Could you create a quick sketch to illustrate what you're trying to do? I don't think it's clear enough.

Comment: anything for you mrdoob <3 http://imgur.com/zc6wwMP

the center is the space ship, id like to raycast from its self the green line start or 0,0,0. to the red maxDistance.  Id then grab the closest intersect with the blue enemy ship array and set it as focus.

moveTowards(focus.poisition){
 var xd = new THREE.Vector3(focus.position.x,focus.position.y,focus.position.z);
 var yd = new THREE.Vector3(shipArr[n].shipMesh.position.x,shipArr[n].shipMesh.position.y,shipArr[n].shipMesh.position.z);
 subvec = subvec.subVectors(xd,yd);}

Comment: Maybe im over thinking it by using ray caster.  I could just iterate over the array of ship enemy's and apply the same math to see the closest subvec.

Comment: Yes instead of casting a ray and going over discovery of already known positions of each enemy I decided not to be an idiot and over think stuff.   check my answer below.  So sorry to waste your valuable time mrdoob PM me and ill show you what im working on =D.

Comment: Good that you figured it out ;) Yep, easier to just check the distances.

Comment: I am although running into massive issues of scope >.< now. Its getting very very annoying.